# JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery.js Tomcat 7 + RichFaces 4

Tags: jsf, richfaces, windows-server-2008, tomcat7

I've been using RichFaces 4 with Tomcat 7. There are no errors when Cleaning and Building the app (NetBeans). When the app is deployed, everything works fine but from time to time the following exception is thrown and I don't know where or what could be the error:

This is the Stack Trace of Tomcat's catalina.log

```
may 07, 2012 3:36:43 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery.js.
may 07, 2012 3:36:43 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: 
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:373)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:283)
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:257)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:205)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.access$100(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:37)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:235)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:368)
    ... 25 more
```

Can someone give me some ideas on where to or how to stop this warning/exception from showing? Why is it getting thrown?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ClientAbortException
> ```

The client has aborted the resource request, because the enduser navigated away in all hurry while the page was still loading. Or because the enduser pressed *Esc* while the page was still loading. Or because the network cable was cut by enduser's 5 year old son with a scissor while the page was still loading. Or because the PC caught fire by a lightning strike while the page was still loading. Etcetera.

It's not predictable nor avoidable. Just ignore them. Hide them if necessary from the logs by logger configuration.

Comment: What about the warning concerning "JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery.js" How can it be lost? I never added it to my project, so I suppose RichFaces has that file in some .jar but still, is there a way to fix it, or can I safely ignore it? Cheers