# Broken Pipe when writing bytes in ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

While executing this code,

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
out.flush();  
out.close();
```

I'm getting this exception frequently and I can't figure out why it's happening.

```
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:358)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:354)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
```

I have a web app running in a linux server, under JBoss 4.2.3 and MySQL.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: That means the client of your servlet hung up the connection for some reason.

Comment: What kind of reason is that? This is an action for a file download, for example.

Comment: Right, maybe the browser that was doing the file download crashed halfway through.  Or their internet connection went down.  Or whatever, the receiver can't accept the bytes you're writing to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClientAbortException at application deployed at jboss with IE8 browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788891/clientabortexception-at-application-deployed-at-jboss-with-ie8-browser), [JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery.js Tomcat 7 + RichFaces 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490028/jsf1064-unable-to-find-or-serve-resource-jquery-js-tomcat-7-richfaces-4) and more.

Comment: BalusC, thanks for the reply. I`ll try ignoring the exception since I can`t control it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically this is due to the client disconnecting. There are several reasons the client may have disconnected (timed out, browser was closed, etc). Also, as general practice, if you didn't open the stream then don't close. More on closing the stream here [Should I close the servlet outputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream).

Answer (score 3):

This can be improved by adding proper 
response.setBufferSize(bufferSizeneeded+200);
The default buffer size is 8124 , Which may not be applicable for all the users ! 
and 
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(exportData.length));