# Large videos not able to play in firefox browser, same videos are properly playing in chrome

Tags: java, firefox

I am getting error when I try to download video from a link which play in browser automatically. For small file less than 15mb play normally,but when I tried to run a large video mp4 file,it gives file is corrupt error. Also I found "Broken Pipe" error in jboss console.

I found above issue in Firefox only, it is working fine in Chrome.

These videos are saved in BLOB format in DB. I have a servlet file to download the videos.

I tried below things, but still I am not able to resolve the issue.

1. [Broken Pipe when writing bytes in ServletOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206754/broken-pipe-when-writing-bytes-in-servletoutputstream)
   I have added below code in our application:
   response.setBufferSize(bufferSizeneeded+200)
   I did not get the “java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe”  error but it give different type error.
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=875573
   Content type changed from “video/mp4” to “video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v”
   It is also not working.
3. [How to fix java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309561/how-to-fix-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe)